# How do I update old Swift code in iOS that overrides supportedInterfaceOrientations function?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have old Swift code in Swift 3 for iOS that overrides the function supportedInterfaceOrientations. I get an error that says:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

now that that function has been made a variable.

When I try to override the variable, I get an error that says:

> Cannot override with a stored property 'supportedInterfaceOrientations'

How do I update that old Swift code? This question should apply to any case when a function becomes a variable in the new framework.

When I choose to instead assign a value to the superclass like this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    supportedInterfaceOrientations = .all

}
```

I get an error saying that `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is a get only variable.

How do I update this old code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update your code you should create the override of the var and make it return the desired value. For example, for supportedInterfaceOrientations it should become the below variable.

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .all
}
```